# Loop through range to find matching string google scripts

Tags: loops, search, google-apps-script, google-sheets, range

I'm trying to loop through the top title row of my spreadsheet to find the index number of a column based on the title name so that if someone inserts a column my code won't break. Here's what I have so far:

```
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('RawData');
  var values = sheet.getRange(1,1,sheet.getMaxRows(),sheet.getMaxColumns()).getValue(); //line that's breaking
  range.setNote("inside function");
  var i = 1;
  while(values[1][i] != name) {
    i++;
  }return i;
}
```

The code appears to break on the line where I set 'values,' and I can't figure out how to access the array I created in order to check which one contains the same string as the 'name' parameter. The setNote line is just for testing purposes, you can ignore it.
Thanks in advance.

EDIT

```
function getColumnByName() {
  var name = "Ready For Testing?";
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('RawData');
  var vA=ss.getRange(1,1,ss.getLastRow(),ss.getLastColumn()).getValues();
  var hA=vA.shift();//returns header array vA still contains the data
  var idx={};
  var index = hA.forEach(function(name,i){idx[name]=i});//idx['header name'] returns index  
  return index;
}
```

I set name just for testing purposes, it will be passed as a parameter when I use the actual function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
function getColumnByName() {
  var name = "Ready For Testing?";
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('RawData');
  var vA=ss.getDataRange().getValues();
  var hA=vA.shift();//returns header array vA still contains the data
  var idx= hA.indexOf(name);
  if(idx === -1 ) throw new Error('Name ' + name + ' was not found');
  return idx + 1; // Returns the name position 
}
```

---

Instead of

```
var values = sheet.getRange(1,1,sheet.getMaxRows(),sheet.getMaxColumns()).getValue();
```

and instead of

```
var vA=ss.getRange(1,1,ss.getLastRow(),ss.getLastColumn()).getValues();
```

use

```
var values = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
```

1. `getValue()` only returns the value of top-left cell
2. using `sheet.getMaxRows()` / `sheet.getMaxColumns()` returns the sheet last row / column which could cause getting a lot of blank rows / columns.
3. compared with the second line code (`getLastRow()` / `getLastColumn()`) the proposed code line is "cheaper" (one call to the Spreadsheet Service instead of three (1. `getRange`,  2. `getLastRow`, 3 `getLastColumn` Vs. `getDataRange`) to get the data range and usually is faster too.

---

Regarding

```
var index = hA.forEach(function(name,i){idx[name]=i});
```

`forEach` returns `undefined` ref. [Array.prototype.forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
function myFunction() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive()
  var sh=ss.getSheetByName('RawData');
  var vA=sh.getRange(1,1,sh.getLastRow(),sh.getLastColumn()).getValues();
  var hA=vA.shift();//returns header array vA still contains the data
  var idx={};
  hA.forEach(function(h,i){idx[h]=i});//idx['header name'] returns index  
  var end="is near";//set a break point here and run it down to here in the debugger and you can see hA and idx
}
```

hA is the header name array

idx is an object that returns the index for a given header name

idx is all you need just learn to put these three lines of code in your script in the future and you won't need to use an external function call to get the index.

```
 var hA=vA.shift();//returns header array vA still contains the data
 var idx={};
 hA.forEach(function(h,i){idx[h]=i});//idx['header name'] returns index  
 vA still contains all of your data
```

Comment: Is this instead of what I have so far, or in addition to it? The code breaks at the last line you wrote and I don't understand where it specifies which string it's looking for, I passed the string in as a parameter on my previous example

Comment: hA is the header name array.  idx is an object that returns the index for a given header name

Comment: I just fixed it

Comment: Yes.  This replaces your code.  Just use idx to the return the index.  I actually just do this in the beginning of my code when I want to write functions that allow the columns to move arround and be replaced.

Comment: Sorry for making so many errors.  My keyboard is giving me problems.

Comment: No worries, I've stepped through it and made some adjustments and most of it seems to work, but for whatever reason I still can't get the last line to cooperate. Index is undefined (see original post for edit)

Comment: May be you didn't get the last update.  I just tested it and it works okay now.

Comment: Sorry, it still doesn't work. I need it to be able to return the index number and when I set a variable to the last line's output it comes out as undefined.

Comment: No your missing the point.  All you need is idx it's an object that returns the index for a given header name.  Just learn to do this right inside your code and you wont have to make external function calls to get the index

Comment: Okay thanks. Next time, a short written explanation rather than just a piece of code would be helpful. It's also generally good practice to house code that will be repeated often in a helper function like I am trying to do, it's a design choice.